# Wordpress: is it possible to create a sticky post that is at the top of the search results no matter the terms searched for?

Tags: wordpress, search, sticky

Title pretty much says it all.  I'd like a post to appear at the top of every search results page.

Google and their support forums turned up nothing.

Any pro's on here want to shed some light if its possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to include a custom field on your posts that would be a checkbox that allows you to mark a post as sticky. Then, in your search.php file, you could write a wp_query that would retrieve the sticky posts (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Then after that is displayed, include your search results loop. So you're calling your sticky posts prior to displaying any of your search results.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I did try displaying a post out of the loop but I wasn't getting the result I wanted.  I'll give this a go right now. Thanks

Comment: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/28/get-the-latest-sticky-posts-in-wordpress

I tried this solution earlier and it didnt work, now it does.  I must've fiddled with something along the way to make it happen but I'm no questioning or touching it again.  The quick reply was appreciated Joe

Comment: Hey, if it works, stick with it. To be honest, until that link you posted, I didn't even realize there was a built-in option to sticky posts. It's not a feature that's ever come up or been requested from any of our clients. Learn something new everyday, right?